# Email sender worker-pool skeleton in go

Tags: go, asynchronous

How to refactor this go code to make it more easy to understand and to maintain?

It is email sender worker-pool skeleton.

To understand the working-pool logic I coded it without real email client and database code.
To simulate the read from database, I used ints, taking them in random groups (0..6 items each) with random sleep times.
Instead of sending real emails, Just printing with random sleeps.

If I add real email client code into it, it will become more complex.

Especially, how to split the code in the main function into smaller functions?

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

// Msg is an email message
type Msg struct {
    From    string
    To      string
    Subject string
    Body    string
}

var r = make(chan int, 100)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Begin")

    q := make(chan Msg)
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal)
    stop := make(chan bool)

    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        sig := <-sigs
        fmt.Println(sig)
        stop <- true
    }()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for m := range q {
                send(m)
            }
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        r <- i
    }
    close(r)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            a, _ := read()
            for _, m := range a {
                q <- m
            }
            select {
            case <-stop:
                close(q)
                return
            case <-time.After(time.Millisecond):
            }
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("End")
}

func read() ([]Msg, error) {
    d := time.Duration(rand.Intn(400)) * time.Millisecond
    time.Sleep(d)
    a := []Msg{}
    c := rand.Intn(6)
    for i := 0; i < c; i++ {
        n := <-r
        m := Msg{"support@example.com", "user" + strconv.Itoa(n) + "@example.com", strconv.Itoa(n), "Test Body"}
        a = append(a, m)
    }
    for _, m := range a {
        fmt.Print(m.Subject, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println("read in", d)
    return a, nil
}

func send(m Msg) {
    d := time.Duration(rand.Intn(700)) * time.Millisecond
    time.Sleep(d)
    fmt.Println(m.Subject, "sent in", d)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Some suggestions to improve the question: 1) Change the title to something like `Email sender worker pool skeleton in go`. 2) Move all the explanations above the code. The current title can make the question off-topic which means it can be closed by the community. See [how to ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance.